# Taking a method in argument

Tags: list, methods, ocaml

I already know that `foldright (+) [1;2;3;4;5] 0` will just sum up the element from right to left using `0` as the accumulator.

Now, suppose `list_obj` a list of objects, where each object has 4 methods, i.e. `method1`, `method2`, `method3` and `method4`. Each of these methods takes no argument and return an integer.

I would like to create a function taking two arguments, i.e. a list and a method.

```
let sum liste methode = foldright (+) (map (fun obj -> obj#methode) liste) 0
```

The purpose of this function is to sum up 4 lists depending on the method used.

So I need to do something like

```
print_int(sum list_obj method1)
print_ing(sum list_obj method2)
print_int(sum list_obj method3)
print_int(sum list_obj method4)
```

I know the programming behind it is wrong. How can I do it anyway?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Methods are not values, they cannot be passed as arguments to function like C++'s method pointers. Consequently in:

```
let sum liste methode = foldright (+) (map (fun obj -> obj#methode) liste) 0
```

the two occurrences of `methode` are completely unrelated from the point of view of the compiler

For your use case, you can use a getter function:

```
let sum getter list = List.fold_left (+) 0 (List.map getter list)
let () = 
  print_int @@ sum (fun obj -> obj#method1) l_obj;
  print_int @@ sum (fun obj -> obj#method2) l_obj
```

Comment: Can you explain what means @@ here?

Comment: `f @@ g x` is the same thing as `f (g x) `, here it avoids forgetting to close the parenthesis after the long expression.